# Webform dynamic select options based upon another element's state

Tags: 8, webforms

Say there are two select elements with dynamic options (via an options alter hook, sourced from an external resource): A and B.  There is also a datasource that provides a relationship that determines the options in B that should shown when a particular selection in A is chosen.

The source data for each element in addition to the relationship data source is not able to be predicted or controlled by Drupal.

For example:

A Options at a particular instant

```
| name | code |
| Group 1 | 1 |
| Group 2 | 2 |
| Group 3 | 3 |
```

B options at a particular instant

```
| name | code |
| Thing 1 |  1 |
| Thing 2 | 2 |
| Thing 3 | 3 |
```

The relationships at any given time.

```
| group | thing |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
```

So if group 1 is selected for A, then things 1, 2, and 3 should be options for B

If group 2 is selected for A, then things 1 and 2 should be options for B

If group 3 is selected, then only thing 3 should be an option for 3.

We are currently implementing this requirement through the core FAPI and ajax callbacks, but would like to covert it to use Webforms.

What would be the recommended approach to take in order to solve this with Webforms?  Please bear in mind that modifying the source data is not an option, as it is not able to be predicted nor controlled by our unit and adjustments must be reflected in realtime.

Comment: Have you tried #state in drupal form using that you can implement.
see this: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states

Comment: above solution is for the custom form.
for Webform try this : https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2012-11-01/drupal-7-dynamic-select-list-in-the#comment-6677046

Comment: I do not believe that states can help, as the options themselves need to change.  Is there a state for that?

Comment: We are using Drupal 8 and the contributed Webform module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one has contributed back a solution for Drupal 8. I think the best approach is going to be to organize cascading select menus using a CSV and implementing something like [Cognito form's cascading dropdowns menus](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/205/building-forms/creating-data-lookups/filtered-lookups#filter-choices-on-your-form-using-cascading-lookups).

Another supported approach is the [Webform Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_shs) module but it requires a taxonomy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for following up.  We are more than willing to do custom development to get this implemented.  Can we somehow trigger rebuilds of a webform similar to how we are doing it with FAPI?

Comment: Webform in D8 is built using FAPI and you can add Ajax callbacks to custom webform elements.